# Complex case class instance updating

Tags: scala

I need to update an instance of a case class, based on a complex logic. What I've come with:

```
case class Thing(i: Int, s: String) {
    def map(f: Thing => Thing): Thing = f(this)
}

def update1(thing: Thing) = {
    var x = thing
    if (true) x = x.copy(i = x.i + 3)
    if (true) x = x.copy(s = x.s.trim)
    if (true) x = x.copy(i = x.i * 7)
    x
}

def update2(thing: Thing) = {
    val x1 = if (true) thing.copy(i = thing.i + 3) else thing
    val x2 = if (true) x1.copy(s = x1.s.trim) else x1
    if (true) x2.copy(i = x2.i * 7) else x2
}

def update3(thing: Thing) = {
    def up1(x: Thing) = if (true) x.copy(i = x.i + 3) else x
    def up2(x: Thing) = if (true) x.copy(s = x.s.trim) else x
    def up3(x: Thing) = if (true) x.copy(i = x.i * 7) else x
    (up1 _).compose(up2).compose(up3)(thing)
}

def update4(thing: Thing) =
    thing
        .map { x => if (true) x.copy(i = x.i + 3) else x }
        .map { x => if (true) x.copy(s = x.s.trim) else x }
        .map { x => if (true) x.copy(i = x.i * 7) else x }
```

Where `if (true)` may be a complex `if..else` or `match`, etc.

I don't like all the variants, except the last one, but it requires `map` function definition, which is not very nice (i.e. the approach is not completely general). Also note that `Thing` is not generic, so I don't need a `Functor` instance + Cats, etc.

Is there an idiomatic way for this task?

Comment: OK, I find my `update4` variant the best.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
val myThing = Thing(1, "destroy all monsters")

val conditionUpdates: Seq[(() => Boolean, Thing => Thing)] = ???

val conditionallyUpdatedThing = conditionUpdates.foldLeft(myThing){
  case(thingAcc, (condition, update)) => 
    if(condition())
      update(thingAcc)
    else
      thingUpdate
}
```

The advantage is you can pass as many conditional updates as you want.

Comment: `() => Boolean` looks a bit useless, no? It's either the same as constant `Boolean`, or something side-effecty. If you let the boolean condition depend on the `Thing` from the previous round, then your `conditionUpdates` become just `Seq[Thing => Thing]`, in which case you can simply `reduce(_ andThen _)`.

Comment: It was not made clear if the Boolean condition was dependent on the Thing instance. If it is then I guess we only need Seq[Thing => Thing] that contains the Boolean check.